# How do I send the "Windows key" to the remote machine with the screen sharing app?

Tags: macos, keyboard, screen-sharing

It seems like the screen sharing app doesn't send "Windows key" presses.

To be clear, I want to be able to press the "Windows key" on my standard PC keyboard so that the machine to which I'm connecting receives it as a single key press. How do I achieve this?

Is there a way to translate, for example, Shift+Option+F12 to send the Windows key? Other advice welcome.

Comment: Command doesn’t work? what version of the host OS and what version of guest (remote) OS are in play?

Comment: Strange that Command does not work. The Windows keypress is essentially a CTRL - ESC, so you could try that if the Command key is not working.

Comment: It may be expecting you to press some other key like command + v.

Comment: I'm connecting to a Fedora 30 machine that runs Openbox. I use the Windows key on Openbox the same way I use it on Windows natively, namely to pop up a menu. I press the Windows key by itself, with no other keys, to achieve this.

Comment: Did CTRL - ESC work?  If Fedora is expecting keycode 93 (the code for the windows key) that might not exactly match up to the Mac keyboard but the Control key does map in windows.  Long story short you might have to change the key map.

Comment: @ThomasNelson no, it did not. I think you might be confused about what ctrl+esc does. It's a windows-specific shortcut, nothing to do with Openbox. It's not a shortcut I want.

Comment: Keycodes for the apple keyboard can be found here... https://eastmanreference.com/complete-list-of-applescript-key-codes. the control key has a different code so you might be able to map that code too.